Git find renames and retain history automatically
I have a commit A, which consists of 1000 modifications/creations/deletions.
Basically 90% of creations/deletions are moves.
I can indeed see it when I run git status --find-renames.
The problem is my PR looks like garbage in Azure DevOps git and its history.
I thought about splitting it into two commits (only moves/creations/deletions AND only changes), but don't know how to do it automatically.
How to solve it?

Do whatever makes the pull request reviewers life easier :-)

It IS what Im trying to do. Also, if it can be done semi-auto it will be perfect.


I thought about splitting it into two commits (only moves/creations/deletions AND only changes), but don't know how to do it automatically.

Automating the process of splitting commits into moves/creations/deletions and changes can be a bit tricky as Git does not provide a built-in way to do this.
Let's manually use Git commands to do this process first.
For example, if your file moves involve fewer paths and file modification involves many paths, you can use the following git command
git add "path to moved file"
git commit -m "File moves"

git add -A  # or git add “path to modified file”
git commit -m "File modifications"

git push

If your file moves involve many paths and file modification involves fewer
paths, you can use the following git command
git add “path to modified file” 
git commit -m "File modifications"

git add -A   # or git add "path to moved file" 
git commit -m "File moves"

git push

Then, you can create a script that uses Git commands to automate this process. Of course you need to pass the paths to the script.

Thanks, I ended up semi-automating. First, I list all renames with git status --find-renames, save them to temp folder. Then hard reseting to remote, applying moves from temp folder, committing, then cherry-picking from remote, mergin with accept-theirs, committing. This way I have two commits: one for moving files, one for changing.

Thanks for sharing your solution!  If possible, you can share your detailed steps as answer, so that it may help others who have the same issue in the future. Happy coding!

Miao's suggested solution already does the job, but unfortunately it avoids the tedious part, consisting of listing and filtering paths. We can use the --diff-filter option for this.
# First we undo your "too big" commit here, while keeping changes
git reset HEAD^

# Then we list (and add) only modified files
git add $(git diff --diff-filter=M --name-only)

# The following is trivial committing
git commit -m "Message for modifications"
git add .
git commit -m "Message for creations/deletes/renames"

(Note that you'll have to push with --force-with-lease to update your PR afterwards, where you'll see your older commit replaced by the two new ones we just made)
